# Recover files on unmounted partition

Tags: osx, data-recovery, unmounting

I have 2 partitions on my macbook, but I can't mount one of them.

When I run the disk utility, the console (show details area) returns the message:

> Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required.Error: Disk Utility can’t repair this disk. Back up as many of your files as possible, reformat the disk, and restore your backed-up files.

I need to recover my files that are on the unmounted partition.

Is there a way to list and recover these files without mounting the partition?

Comment: I've seen this kind of message on a FS that had gone corrupted and couldn't be recovered because it was too full (which is why Apple recommends you never to fill up your FS at more than 85%). I was able to mount it read-only from a Live Linux CD though (with force option) IIRC

Answer (score 1):

if you can boot into a live image and have an external hard drive or thumb drive you can use `dd` to copy the disk to another file.

```
dd bs=512 if=/dev/<your disk> of=/some_dir/foo.dmg conv=noerror,sync
```